# unmarshall error when trying to configurable settings for component in istioctl

Tags: json, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I try to install istioctl with the default profile but with a twist, I want to specify an IP address. According to this [doc](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/) I can do it that way :

```
istioctl install  --set components.ingressGateways.loadBalancerIP=1.2.3.4
```

but then an error show up :

```
Error: generate config: could not unmarshal merged YAML: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []json.RawMessage
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be components.ingressGateway.k8s.service.loadBalancerIP? https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/#GatewaySpec

Comment: Thanks, I changed the path, and use an yaml file instead (even if it change nothing) it work now.